# Why does my call to AcceptEx return 10022 WSAEINVAL?

Tags: sockets, winsock2

The answer to the question should be a community wiki-style list of all possible reasons, so you can go through the checklist and verify you did everything right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You forgot to call listen() on sListenSocket!
2. Your sAcceptSocket is already bound/connected.
3. You accidentally called AcceptEx twice using the same sAcceptSocket! (like [C# socket error 10022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707214/c-sharp-socket-error-10022))
4. ...(more reasons here if there are any)